# Why console.log shows me that there are 0 loaded images in the html document?

Tags: javascript, preloader

I have been making preloader based on counting images in the html document according to one youtube tutorial.

I got stuck and don't understand why console.log command says that the amount of loaded images is 0, though I have some images in the html document.

I have made the codesandbox so that one could easily see the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/preloader-mip2o?file=/app.js

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens, because JavaScript works asynchronously.
I've added 1 line to `image_loaded` function:

```
function image_loaded() {
  alert("In image_loaded")
  images_loaded_count++;
...
```

After that I run it in browser and see that console.log is called before images are actually loaded.

Comment: Thank you! It was a stupid mistake from my side regarding console.log :)